# How to grant authority of insert with default values in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant

Postgres can insert with default values:

```
INSERT INTO users DEFAULT VALUES;
```

But can't grant authority.

```
☓ GRANT INSERT () ON users TO authenticated_user;
☓ GRANT INSERT DEFAULT VALUES ON users TO authenticated_user;
```